# Throwing captured exception results in CompositeException

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

In the following code, I get an EmptyResultSetException when no more records are read from the Sqlite database. This is expected. This exception is caught in doOnError. If I throw this exception, the exception caught in the subscriber's onError handler becomes a CompositeException. The CompositeException contains a list of exceptions and in this case it only contains a single exception which happens to be the EmptyResultSetException. Originally, before changing my code, the EmptyResultSetException was sent directly to the subscriber's onError handler. Now it gets placed into a CompositeException. What could be causing this?

```
val msgToSendPublisher = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(MessageToSend())

msgToSendPublisher
    .flatMap { _ ->
        App.context.repository.getMessageToSend().flatMapObservable { messageToSend -> Observable.just(messageToSend) }
    }
    .doOnError { error ->

        throw error
    }
    .doOnNext {
        msgToSendPublisher.onNext(it)
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { messageToSend ->

        },
        { ex ->
            if (ex !is EmptyResultSetException) {

            }
        },
        {
        }
    )
```

Comment: `throw error`. There is no reason to throw from `doOnError` as it will relay the original exception by default.

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doOnError-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-

Comment: @akarnokd That is correct. I removed the throw and it worked. Thanks!